# How to access variables set using app.set() in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do i access the variables set using express's `app.set()` for e.g

```
app.set('view engine','jade');
app.set('jsDirectory',/js/');
```

From the guide, i understand that i can access the same using `app.get(<key>)`, but this is the output of `console.log(app.get('view engine'))`.

```
{ router:
   { app:
      { stack: [Object],
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _connections: 0,
        connections: [Getter/Setter],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _handle: null,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        cache: {},
        settings: [Object],
        redirects: {},
        isCallbacks: {},
        _locals: [Object],
        dynamicViewHelpers: {},
        errorHandlers: [],
        route: '/',
        routes: [Circular],
        router: [Getter],
        root: 'C:\\Users\\Shahal\\Works\\App',
        models: {},
        extensions: {},
        disconnectSchemas: [Function: disconnectSchemas],
        passport: [Object] },
     routes: {},
     params: {},
     _params: [],
     middleware: [Function] } }
```

Comment: It sounds like you might be running express 2.x? The documentation on expressjs.com is documentation for express 3.x.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

They become available through the app.settings object:

```
app.set('oneSetting', 'one');
app.set('twoSetting', 'two');
app.set('view engine','jade');

console.log(app.settings.oneSetting);
console.log(app.settings.twoSetting);
console.log(app.settings['view engine']);
```

Answer (score 23):

I know this is 2 years old, but it is still the first link that pops up on google so i thought this could be appropriate.

You could also set your variable like that

```
     app.set('port', 3000);
```

And later get it with

```
     app.get('port');
```

I prefer that approach because it's shorter and more straight forward. It is also the way they use in the [Express 4.x documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.get).

```
    app.get(name)
    Returns the value of name app setting, where name is one of strings in the app settings table.
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but 'port' isn't listed in the [app settings table](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.settings.table), so how does this work?

Comment: @KnewB If it is not there before, express will create the new one and assign the value.

Comment: but why we cant get a variable that is set in a different file ( file1.js ) and even though file1.js is executed before we execute get() function.

Answer (score -3):

```
app.set('view engine','hbs')
**All are correct:**
app.get('view engine')
app.locals.settings['view engine']
app.settings['view engine']
```