# Express: accessing app.set() settings in routes

Tags: node.js, express

In Express, I'm led to believe that global app settings can be created by doing something similar to the following in my main `app.js` file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    ...
    login = require('./routes/login');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  ...
  app.set('ssoHostname', 'login.hostname.com');
  ...
});
...
app.get('/login', login.login);
...
```

now in `./routes/login.js`, I'd like to access `app.settings.ssoHostname`, but if I attempt to run anything similar to (as per: [How to access variables set using app.set() in express js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13361072)):

```
...
exports.login = function(req, res) {
  var currentURL = 'http://' + req.header('host') + req.url;
  if (!req.cookies.authCookie || !User.isValidKey(req.cookies.authCookie)) {
    res.redirect(app.settings.ssoHostname + '/Login?returnURL=' + encodeURIComponent(currentURL));
  }
};
...
```

it does not recognize `app`:

```
ReferenceError: app is not defined
```

My questions are:

1. Is the approach I took of using `app.set()` for global settings that will be re-used often the "proper" way to do it and if so...
2. How do I access these settings in routes?
3. If not using `app.set()` for global settings to be used often, how would I set and get custom settings in routes?

Comment: You can use req.app.settings.ssHostName

Comment: req.app.settings is a great shout.. just what I was looking for.  Thanks @Hector Correa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of your `app.js` file:

```
module.exports = app;
```

And then in `routes/login.js`:

```
var app = require('../app');
```

Now you have access to the actual `app` object and won't get a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: Never do that, because this assumes the same app instance is used in all the application..

Comment: if I want to access app.locals from other file (like routes/blah.js), what is the best practice?

Comment: req.app.locals would be the best practice?

Comment: please consider accepting Darius/Spudley answer. This accepted answer is incorrect

Answer (score 107):

Use `req.app.get('ssoHostname')`

Comment: This works for me. I'm using a config.json with app-settingvalues for dev and prod.

Comment: Any idea why this is undocumented?  Tracing the git history back it seems like this has worked for a long time (at least since 2011).

Comment: All request/response objects have an attribute `app` which references the Express application which is handling that request/response.  

In addition to `req.app.get('ssoHostname')`, you can also use `req.app.settings.ssoHostname`.

Comment: How to I get anyObj from routes/index.js ?

    //app.js

    const app = express()
    const routes = require('./routes')
    app.use('/', routes)

    app.set('anyObj', {})


    // routes/index.js
    const express = require('express')
    const router = express.Router()

    const users = require('./users')
    router.use('/api/users', users)