# NodeJS, Circular dependency: main module not in the cache?

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

I am trying to access Express 'app' variable in one of the sub-modules of my application.
One way of doing it is to pass it as an argument when calling sub-module, but I would like to avoid it. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822584/express-accessing-app-set-settings-in-routes#answer-14822617) mentions that it is possible, however every time I try it I get exception saying that object is not a function (traceback below)

**server.coffee**

```
express = require 'express'

# Application Config
config = require './lib/config/config'
app = express()

# Start server
server = app.listen config.port, ->
  logger.info "Express server listening on port #{config.port} in #{app.get("env")} mode"

# load procesor
fooBarStreamProcessor = require('./lib/modules/fooBarStreamProcessor')
fooBarUpstream = new fooBarStreamProcessor(config.fooBar_host, config.fooBar_port)

# Expose app
exports = module.exports = app
```

**fooBarStreamProcessor.coffee**

```
  events             = require('events')
  eventEmitter       = new events.EventEmitter()
  app = require("../../server")

  console.log(app.get('something'))

  module.exports = ->
    return "I am some function"
```

**traceback**

```
  TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/devel/exampleproj/server.coffee:30:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/devel/exampleproj/server.coffee:1:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.loadFile (~/devel/exampleproj/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:16:19)
    at Module.load (~/devel/exampleproj/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/devel/exampleproj/lib/modules/fooBarStreamProcessor.coffee:9:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/devel/exampleproj/lib/modules/fooBarStreamProcessor.coffee:1:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.loadFile (~/devel/exampleproj/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:16:19)
    at Module.load (~/devel/exampleproj/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/devel/exampleproj/server.coffee:3:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/devel/exampleproj/server.coffee:1:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Upon inspection, the `fooBarStreamProcessor` seems to be set to `{}` instead of actual function required from `fooBarStreamProcessor.coffee`.
While troubleshooting, I've tried to include something like `require("./server")` in a first line of `server.coffee` and it got rid of the error, but the code was executed twice.

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - it was Coffeescripts global wrapper causing the problem.
Compiling coffeescript with `'-b'` (bare) option stops this from happening. Interestingly enough, running coffeescript in place (without `-c` flag) causes the same error to show up.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that this line would be executed **after** you're including the submodule:

```
# Expose app
exports = module.exports = app
```

Try moving it up to the app definition:

```
app = module.exports = express()
```

And make sure you set anything you need on the app before requiring the submodule.

Comment: Changed it as suggested above but the error is exactly the same.
You can try yourself, I have uploaded example code to https://github.com/skrobul/cyclic-deps-problem/archive/master.zip

Comment: This must be a coffeescript bug. I made the change suggested, compiled to JS, and it seemed to work fine. I'm not very familiar with coffeescript, so maybe someone else can help out with that bit.

Comment: thanks, you pointed me in correct direction. It was indeed coffeescript's global function wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a circular dependency. Usually this means loading one later at the time it's needed instead of at the beginning of the file, but it's not clear from your sample code when this would be. In `fooBarStreamProcessor.coffee` you could require `server` inside the function you're exporting.

```
events             = require('events')
eventEmitter       = new events.EventEmitter()

module.exports = ->
  app = require("../../server")
  console.log(app.get('something'))

  return "I am some function"
```