# Versioning for SPA/AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, versioning, single-page-application

I have SPA/AngularJs application that I run with very simple nodejs/express server, just serve as static. 
And I need to handle different versions of a website for different users.
Mean UserA can access versions [1.1, 1.5-beta]. UserB can access [2.0]. For example.

What is the best way to handle that?

P.S I also use requirejs to load js files, maybe this can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your issue clearly, but please check this link

[Express: accessing app.set() settings in routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822584/express-accessing-app-set-settings-in-routes)